# flutter (google_maps_flutter) variable

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to change the coordinates to be taken from the Internet
I tried many ways, but it doesn't work
[image]

[image]

```
  RxDouble locationmap1 = 11.620215.obs ;
  RxDouble locationmap2 = 12.025192.obs ;
  Completer<GoogleMapController> controller = Completer();
  static final CameraPosition kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng (hhh,locationmap2.value),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't show code as images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the variables static:

```
static RxDouble locationmap1 = 11.620215.obs ;
static RxDouble locationmap2 = 12.025192.obs ;
  Completer<GoogleMapController> controller = Completer();
  static final CameraPosition kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng (locationmap1.value,locationmap2.value),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );
```